# Disable function declaration error in avr g++

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, arduino, avr-gcc

I am using this [Makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile/blob/master/arduino-mk/Arduino.mk) to compile my Arduino sketches which has the following flags for CPP and C

```
CPPFLAGS      += -mmcu=$(MCU) -DF_CPU=$(F_CPU) -DARDUINO=$(ARDUINO_VERSION) \
            -I. -I$(ARDUINO_CORE_PATH) -I$(ARDUINO_VAR_PATH)/$(VARIANT) \
            $(SYS_INCLUDES) $(USER_INCLUDES) -g -Os -w -Wall \
            -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
CFLAGS        = -std=gnu99
CXXFLAGS      = -fno-exceptions
```

when I compile a cpp file, I am getting a fatal error if the functions are used before they are declared. I went through the [avr g++ options](http://linux.die.net/man/1/avr-g++) and found that the option -Wimplicit-function-declaration enables it. Also it is enabled by the -Wall option, which is used in the make file.

I want to enable -Wall option (since it enables lot of other warnings) but disable only -Wimplicit-function-declaration option.

I checked the documentation, but couldn't figure out how to do this. Can someone kindly tell me how to do it?

Comment: I have to compile some Arduino code. By default the Arduino IDE doesn't force it, because of which most of the Arduino sketches don't declare the functions. I declaring all my functions before using them in the new code which I write, but fixing all existing code seemed a pain, that's why I want to do this.

Comment: How could such code possibly work? For example, if the compiler sees `foo(0, 0);`, how does it know whether to pass the zeroes as integers, pointers, floats, or whatever? Heck, the declaration could even be `void foo(int, int, int = 0);` and the compiler has to call `foo` with *three* parameters. How could it generate the right code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't disable that error when compiling C++ code - it's a fatal error, not a warning.

You can (but shouldn't) get away with it for C code (with `-Wno-implicit-function-declaration`), but that can't work for C++.

```
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wno-implicit-function-declaration" 
                  is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it is not possible in C++. I just found that the Arduino IDE adds these function prototypes automatically (https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/app/src/processing/app/preproc/PdePreprocessor.java). I guess I should abstract this code out and add it to my Makefile.

Comment: I upvoted this because it's very useful when compiling ancient bits. It's fine to write correct new code, but it's completely unreasonable to have to rewrite every bit of working code from the bad old days.

Answer (score 0):

refer to;
http://arduino.cc/en/Main/FAQ#.UyUa8vmSz99

quote

> In fact, you already are; the Arduino language is merely a set of
>   C/C++ functions that can be called from your code. **Your sketch
>   undergoes minor changes (e.g. automatic generation of function
>   prototypes)** and then is passed directly to a C/C++ compiler
>   (avr-g++)

more info;
http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/BuildProcess#.UyUa6vmSz98

the windows arduino IDE will preprocess the function declartion prototypes before passing it to the compiler.

you'll need to build this pre-processing into your arduino makefile project if you want to replicate the arduino IDE.

Comment: Yeah I kind of figured it out after I posted this question and added this as an restriction in my makefile.